# File getting locked when Ubuntu system is restarted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I have a file called as `x.json` while is being written by the node.js service. When I stop the node.js service and start it again, `x.json` is getting locked and cannot be opened by node.js service to start writing into the file. Node.js service throws error as `EACCES: permission denied, open 'x.json'`. 
`ls -l x.json` shows `-rw-r--r--`, but still unable to open the file even using `vim`.

Comment: give necessary permission to file using 'sudo chmod 777 /filepath'

Comment: Don't do 777; you don't need that. Do 666.